# Get 2nd, 3rd line from a multi-line string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, error-handling

Simply put, I'm trying to read the 2nd (and 3rd, etc) line from a multi-line string. Is there a way in Javascript to extract the file name and line number from an error.stack output? For example, in the code sample below, refer 2nd line, I want to get the value within the parenthesis (CampaignController.js:229:30).

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSampleData' of undefined
    at proto.constructor.getFunctionName (http://clientservices.local:44085/sample/controllers/CampaignController.js:229:30)
    at proto.constructor.r [as getFunctionName] (http://clientservices.local:44085/sample/lib/lodash/lodash.min-v3.9.3.js:25:494)
    at proto.constructor.showModal (http://clientservices.local:44085/sample/controllers/CampaignController.js:116:30)
    at proto.constructor.r [as showModal] (http://clientservices.local:44085/sample/lib/lodash/lodash.min-v3.9.3.js:25:494)
    at http://clientservices.local:44085/sample/controllers/CampaignController.js:1268:22
```

I'm doing this to create a server log that sends all UI related exceptions to my server. I need to attach info such as file name and line no as well.

I am able to assign this string (the code below) to a variable, (`var errorStackString = error.stack`), but I am not sure how to go about extracting parts of a string as they fall on a new line. I'm looking at regular expressions to do this. But so far all I've gotten is the 1st line only (which I can get directly using `error.message`)

Also, I understand this can be done using `error.fileName`, `error.columnNumber`, etc, but this currently works in Firefox only. I'm looking to get the fileNames, columnNames on Chrome as well. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: Try using a regex

Comment: Yes, something like [`/^\S.*\r?\n.*?(\w+[^\/:]*:\d+:\d+)\)$/m`](https://regex101.com/r/n10qwy/1) (and access Group 1 value).